# Product Sum for two rows from two dataframes and add sum to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 df as
Main df

```
main_df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(3,9).reshape(-1,2), columns = list('AB'))

    A   B
0   3   4
1   5   6
2   7   8
```

weights df

```
w_df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,5).reshape(-1,2), columns = ['wA','wB'])/10

    wA  wB
0   0.1 0.2
1   0.3 0.4
```

I need to multiply specific row from weights df into all columns of main df and put the summation into a column in main df so output should be like **in case of** using 1st row from weights df

Prod Sum of 1st row in main  = 0.1 * 3 + 0.2 *4 = 1.1

Prod Sum of 2nd row in main  = 0.1 * 5 + 0.2 *6 = 1.7

Prod Sum of 3rd row in main  = 0.1 * 7 + 0.2 *8 = 2.3

i.e. output of main df should be like (in case of using 1st row from weights df)

```
    A   B   prod_sum
0   3   4   1.1
1   5   6   1.7
2   7   8   2.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are interested in just the first row of `w_df`, you select just that row, multiply `main_df` with it, using the [mul](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) function, along the row axis; after the product computation, you can them sum along the axis.

```
main_df.assign(prod_sum=main_df.mul(w_df.iloc[0].array, axis=1).sum(1))

    A   B   prod_sum
0   3   4   1.1
1   5   6   1.7
2   7   8   2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a dot product:

```
main_df.dot(w_df.iloc[0].values)
```

or

```
main_df @ w_df.iloc[0].values
```

Output:

```
0    1.1
1    1.7
2    2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

main_df['product1'] = main_df['A'] * w_df.loc[0, 'wA]
Repeat for product2/B/wB

Then

main_df['sum'] = main_df['product1'] + main_df['product2']

Hope this helps, certainly a better way. Cheers.